Wordpress payment
Firstly i have designed a website for currency exchange, however i want to set a £1 set fee and How To Easily Accept Payments Without eCommerce On Your WordPress once the individual has selected the exchange between 2 currency, they should be able to make a payment to an account () by entering their vital information. For example if they want to exchange/transfer £100 into Euros, they can click a pay button and then it should take you to a check out page which will result in them having to send/pay £100 + 1 into the account (Website owners) whom will exchange their money for them and send it to a recipient's account. I am currently using  Currency Converter Widget plug in to display the exchange rates. Ive been able to use Stripe however, is there another way to set it up without using stripe ?
